# Visual Studio open new file in non-active window

Tags: visual-studio

Everytime I open a new file or press `go to definition` or `go to implementation`, the editor opens a new file tab beside what I currently am editing, and replacing the file I was seeing. I find this annoying, since I'd lose focus/context on where I was, particularly in complicated project structures. Is there a way to configure VS so that clicking a new file opens it in a new side-to-side window, or an existing non-active side-to-side window?

Comment: Press Alt+F12 instead of F12.  Or right-click > Peek Definition.